# How to coordonate threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I have a little issue and I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

The purpose of the code is to use 3 different threads to display the sequence:
(abc)*

The output shows only one 'A' ...

```
sem_t mutex;
char turn = 'a';

void displayA()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
       sem_wait(&mutex);
       if (turn == 'a')
        {
            printf("A");
            turn = "b";
            printf("%c", turn);
        }
       sem_post(&mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}



int main()
{

    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    pthread_t thread1_id;
    pthread_t thread2_id;
    pthread_t thread3_id;


    pthread_create(&thread1_id, NULL, displayA, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2_id, NULL, displayB, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3_id, NULL, displayC, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread1_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3_id, NULL);

    //sem_destroy(&mutex);

    printf("\n END main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks you for any help

Comment: Do you want to associate each character to one thread or you just want a thread to print a letter? If it's the second one you just need a simple lock and a character that represents what to print. You acquire the lock, see what you need to print, release the lock. You can also do it (easily) with semaphores. You must also implement the logic to print all other characters in your sequence

Comment: The code you posted would not compile because it is missing `displayB` and `displayC`. Also, `turn = "b"` will be flagged. Please post your full code that compiles and links cleanly

Comment: I couldn't post all my code because it was too long, but the functions displayB and displayC exist:

Comment: @JohnDoe Posting code that does not compile cleanly is a red flag, indicating to the reader that you are already misinterpreting what you think you're seeing. Post a [mcve]. The stackoverflow interface should allow you to post your minimal example program.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the `#include` statements needed for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files are needed?

Comment: When posting code, read the link [mcve]  then post code that is short and still displays the problem

Comment: one obvious problem is no code exists to output `B` nor `C`.

Comment: the semaphores are completely unnecessary.  If anything, I would suggest using 3 mutexes.  Where each successive thread waits for the prior mutex to be unlocked before calling print.

Comment: regarding: `void displayA()`    This is not a valid signature for a thread function.  The valid signature is: `void * displayA( void *arg )`